# Cannot access the ADLS account '(accountname)'

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am attempting to use azure data factory v2 to copy data to an Azure data lake store sink.  I have created the data lake store, created an AD web application following the [article here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-service-to-service-authenticate-using-active-directory), and made sure that the account has access to the data lake store.  However, I receive the following error whenever I try to run a pipeline involving a single copy activity that uses the data lake store as a sink:

> Activity Copy *(copy activity name)* failed: Failed to detect region of linked service 'AzureDataLakeStore' : 'LS_DataLakeStore' with error 'Cannot access the ADLS account '*(data lake store account name)*'. Please make sure it has been created.', please explicitly specify the location of the integration runtime referred by the connectVia property to avoid region detection if needed.

I have triple checked that the account name is correct.  I've granted the AD application 'Owner' access to the subscription just to make sure it's not a permissions issue.  And I even attempted to create an Adf Integration Runtime so I can specify it via the 'connectVia' property as suggested by the error, all with no luck.

Ideas on why ADF can't seem to see my data lake store?

Here is my Linked Service json:

```
{
  "name": "LS_DataLakeStore",
  "properties": {
    "type": "AzureDataLakeStore",
    "typeProperties": {
      "dataLakeStoreUri": "adl://{my adls account name}.azuredatalakestore.net/",
      "servicePrincipalId": "{the application id of the AD account I created}",
      "servicePrincipalKey": {
        "type": "SecureString",
        "value": "{the value of the key for the AD account I generated}"
      },
      "tenant": "{my tenant id (I also tried using the tenant domain name here as well)}",
      "subscriptionId": "{the subscription id in which the ADF and ADLS are located}",
      "resourceGroupName": "{the resource group name in which the ADF and ADLS are located}"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. make sure the subscriptionId, resourceGroupName you provide in the linkeservice typeProperties are indeed ones that the data lake account belongs to.
2. make sure you have grant at least "Reader" role to the user/Serviceprincipal on the data lake account, here is how to make it:

   a.     Go to Azure Portal, find the Data Lake Store account

   b.     Click “Access Control (IAM)” on the blade of the Data Lake Store

   c.     Click "Add" in the blade of "Access Control (IAM)"

   d.     Set "Role" to "Reader", and specify the AAD app you created
3. If still doesn't work, please try specify an execution location.

   For ADFV1, executionLocation is a property for copy activity "typeProperties";

   "activities":[
     {
       "name": "SqlServertoAzureSearchIndex",
       "description": "copy activity",
       "type": "Copy",
       ...
       "typeProperties": {
         "source": {
           "type": "SqlSource”
         },
         "sink": {
           "type": "AzureSearchIndexSink"
         },
         "executionLocation": "West US",
       },
      ...
     }
   ]

For ADFV2, specify a connectVia on your AzureDataLakeStoreLinkedService to link to a CloudIR like this:

```
"integrationRuntimes": [
        {
            "name": "cloudIR",
            "properties": {
                "type": "Managed",
                "typeProperties": {
                    "computeProperties": {
                        "location": "East US 2"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
```

Comment: 2. is an important one. I had this exact error, and whilst all my auth settings and linked service set up was fine, it was a lack of access to read metadata that caused it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for using Azure Data Factory, Andrew.

Based on your attached linked service payload, I think you are using "service principal authentication" for your Azure Data Lake Store followed by the guidance here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-data-lake-store#using-service-principal-authentication, right?

Generally the error should be caused by that the provided service principal doesn't have the permission to detect the Azure Data Lake Store's region. Please grant at least "Reader" role in account access control (IAM) on the Azure Data Lake Store. Detail steps:

1. Go to Azure Portal, find the Data Lake Store account
2. Click “Access Control (IAM)” on the blade of the Data Lake Store
3. Click "Add" in the blade of "Access Control (IAM)"
4. Set "Role" to "Reader", and specify the AAD app you created

After that, please try to re-run the Copy Activity.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to tell ADF to use a specific Integration Runtime in V2, as opposed to relying on auto-region detection using the Default IR.

First, create a new Integration Runtime in the region where your Azure Data Lake Store is located:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-azure-integration-runtime#create-azure-ir

Then add the connectVia property to your Azure Data Lake Store Linked Service using a reference to that new IR:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-datasets-linked-services#linked-service-json